# Getting a sudden error on Magento backend / frontend

Tags: magento-1.6

Our webshop has been working fine for a while, today this error shows up on frontend:

There has been an error processing your request

```
Invalid backend model specified: ultramegamenu/category_attribute_backend_grid_columns
```

and this shows up in backend whenever I try to enter "category" menu item:

```
Source model "ultramegamenu/category_attribute_source_dropdown_type" not found for element "umm_dd_type"
```

It appears to be traces from an old theme that was installed on the server and present on the FTP, yet it was not enabled - I have removed all traces of the old theme in /app and /skin, and de-activated whatever modules remained that had relevance to it.

What could be causing this?

EDIT: Thank you for all your answers guys, but I figured it out with Adarsh! +1

Comment: Looks like you had `umm_dd_type` attribute which is missing.

Comment: Alright, Adarsh thanks for the quick reponse, how do you suppose I could fix it? I don't necessarily know where it's supposed to be located

Comment: Go to your `ultramegamenu` (in community or local) and then go to `Block/category/attribute/source/dropdown/type.php`, look for `umm_dd_type` if that exist there, try to find what kind of attribute was it.

Comment: I found type.php in `/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity` there appears to be no traces when searching for "umm_dd_type" or the likes of it, I don't quite know what you mean by "Go to your `ultramegamenu` (in community or local)" ?

Comment: That is core file, it must be inside `community or local`.

Comment: I found a folder `ultramegamenu` in `local` could deleting it perhaps solve it? it shouldn't even be trying to get it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25222/discussion-between-adarsh-khatri-and-mus).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to delete/deactivate any extension, then first place to look at is `etc/modules`. You have to find corresponding file of extension and delete it.

Or simply open it and set `<active>false</active>`. This will make sure your extension is deleted/disabled.

However, if you store had some attribute related to this which is looks like your case, you will need to go to your database and find `eav_attribute` table and then find your attribute `umm_dd_type` in `attribute_code` column and delete it.

**PS Before doing this please make backup of your database and files/folder**

Answer (score 1):

Go to database:

1) make a full backup

2) Run the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `eav_attribute`
WHERE `backend_model` = 'ultramegamenu/category_attribute_backend_grid_columns';
```

3) remove found row

Answer (score 0):

What this looks like is an extension, ultramegamenu, has added an attribute with a custom backend model. However, it seems that the extension either doesn't have the required class for the backend model, or has been removed or disabled so magento can't load the class. What I would do is look in your eav_attribute table for an attribute with that backend model and go from there.

If you don't need that attribute anymore you could simply remove the row, otherwise you need to debug why the class can't be found. Perhaps that extension has been removed or has been disabled in app/etc/modules

Answer (score 0):

I hope  `umm_dd_type` is a `select or  drop down  category eav attribute`.

Guess you have creating `this attribute using installer`.As you have `creating dropdown and  multi selection` .As per as system ,you need add source  `model for this attribute which is save it option and label`.

I hope `ultramegamenu/category_attribute_source_dropdown_type`” means(class ) `does  not define option and labels.So this error occurs`.

Guss that this attribute may be create from a 3rd partly module.

You have `remove this module` or

this Attribute `Source Class` `3RdPartlyNameSpace_3RdPartlyModuleName_Model_Category_Attribute_Source_Dropdown_Type` is missing from system.

For remove this error you need follow @Neklo.com answer.