# Error Magento backend

Tags: magento-1.7

I got the exact same issue as mentioned in this topic: 
[Getting a sudden error on Magento backend / frontend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72263/getting-a-sudden-error-on-magento-backend-frontend)

But i can't find any solution on the problem in the topic?

Hope anyone can help :).

This is the error message i get, when i try to enter 'category' in the backend:

```
    Invalid backend model specified: ultramegamenu/category_attribute_backend_grid_columns

Trace:
#0 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(346): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid backend...')
#1 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(640): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getBackend()
#2 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1624): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->walkAttributes('backend/afterLo...', Array)
#3 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(964): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_afterLoad(Object(Aitoc_Aitpermissions_Model_Rewrite_CatalogCategory))
#4 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(698): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Aitoc_Aitpermissions_Model_Rewrite_CatalogCategory), '362', NULL)
#5 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->load(Object(Aitoc_Aitpermissions_Model_Rewrite_CatalogCategory), '362', NULL)
#6 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitpermissions/Block/Adminhtml/Store/Switcher.php(102): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('362')
#7 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/aitpermissions/store_switcher.phtml(213): Aitoc_Aitpermissions_Block_Adminhtml_Store_Switcher->getAllStores()
#8 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(412): include('/home/www/p1965...')
#9 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(274): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#10 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(288): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#11 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#12 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitpermissions/Block/Adminhtml/Store/Switcher.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Aitoc_Aitpermissions_Block_Adminhtml_Store_Switcher->_toHtml()
#14 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('stores', true)
#16 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/aitpermissions/permissions_advanced.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('stores')
#17 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(412): include('/home/www/p1965...')
#18 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(274): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#19 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/var/ait_rewrite/Mage_Core_Block_Template.php(288): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Aitoc_Aitsys_Model_Rewriter_Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/local/Aitoc/Aitpermissions/Block/Rewrite/AdminPermissionsEditroles.php(27): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Aitoc_Aitpermissions_Block_Rewrite_AdminPermissionsEditroles->_prepareLayout()
#24 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Codnitive_Extifcon_Model_Core_Layout))
#25 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/permi...', 'adminhtml.permi...')
#26 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/permi...', 'adminhtml.permi...')
#27 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#28 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#29 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#30 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#31 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#32 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/RoleController.php(44): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#33 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/RoleController.php(105): Mage_Adminhtml_Permissions_RoleController->_initAction()
#34 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Permissions_RoleController->editRoleAction()
#35 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('editrole')
#36 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#37 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#38 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#39 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/index.php(241): Mage::run('', 'store')
#40 {main}

Error log record number: 1124087455
```

Answer (score 1):

run this query on the db

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where backend_model = 'ultramegamenu/category_attribute_backend_grid_columns'
```

and remove all the rows you find.
Or you can simply delete them by running this code:

```
DELETE FROM eav_attribute where backend_model = 'ultramegamenu/category_attribute_backend_grid_columns'
```

but it's a good idea to check first what you are deleting.

Comment: I tried to run the following command, and deleted the row in the db @Marius.


`code` But now it says:
 Invalid backend model specified: ultramegamenu/category_attribute_backend_dropdown_blocks

Trace:
#0 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(346): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid backend...')
#1 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(640): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getBackend()...`

Comment: Do the same thing for the new invalid model

Comment: So instead you want me to write:

`SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where backend_model = 'ultramegamenu/category_attribute_backend_dropbown_blocks'`

and the same thing for deleting it?

`DELETE FROM eav_attribute where backend_model = 'ultramegamenu/category_attribute_backend_dropdown_blocks'`

But i was wondering, dont the magento shop need this sql rows for later? Or are they being created again, when the magenta shop need it? @Marius

Comment: I can't find anything when i try to search the DB for `SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where backend_model = 'ultramegamenu/category_attribute_backend_dropbown_blocks'`.

Is it the right thing i'm trying to look up @Marius? :)

Comment: Those rows are leftovers from an extension that was uninstalled. Delete what you find. Backup the db just in case and clear the cache after each delete.

Comment: Okay thanks.

But when i search for : SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where backend_model = 'ultramegamenu/category_attribute_backend_dropbown_blocks'

In the DB, i doesn't find anything. Is it the correct line i use for searching? @Marius.

The new error is:

backend model specified: ultramegamenu/category_attribute_backend_dropdown_blocks Trace: #0 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abs‌​tract.php(346):

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: Yes i have cleared the cache @Marius

Comment: After i cleared the cache, i can see there is a new error code, any suggestions what to do @Magnus ? I can't find anything in the database if i try to look up: `SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where backend_model = 'ultramegamenu/category_attribute_source_dropdown_type'`

New error code
`There has been an error processing your request
Source model "ultramegamenu/category_attribute_source_dropdown_type" ikke fundet for egenskaben "umm_dd_type"

Trace:
#0 /home/www/p196560/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "u...')`

Comment: the new error message says something about the `Source model `. So look for `SELECT * FROM eav_attribute where source_model = 'ultramegamenu/category_attribute_source_dropdown_type'`

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I now deleted the db files, but now when i press categories, i just meets a blank page. Any suggestions @Marius :)?

Comment: https://github.com/ticketscript/ticketscript/pull/3028

Comment: It doesn't seems like the link is working @Marius

Comment: @Adarsh Khatri can you help :)?